# This annotation is not applicable to target 'local variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

I want to get value from application.yml, but I got "This annotation is not applicable to target 'local variable" for this part，how to solve this problem?

```
@Value("\${aws.secretsManager.secretName}")
val secretName: String? = ""
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties

fun getSecret() {

        @Value("\${aws.secretsManager.secretName}")
        val secretName: String? = ""


        val region = "us-west-2"
        val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetSecretConfig::class.java)

        // Create a Secrets Manager client
        val client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build()
        val getSecretValueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(secretName)

        var getSecretValueResult: GetSecretValueResult? = try {
            client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest)
        } 
}
```

application.yml

```
aws:
  secretsManager:
    secretName: "test-mvp"
    region: "us-west-2"
    user: "root"
    password: "root"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `@Value` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html):

> Annotation used at the **field or method/constructor parameter level** that indicates a default value expression for the annotated element.

The `@Value` annotation is defined as follow:

```java
@Target(value = {FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(value = RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Value
```

As you see by the `@Target`, the `@Value` annotation it's not intended  to be used in a `LOCAL_VARIABLE`.

The solution is to define the `secretName` variable outside of the function - as a field of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround logic here:

(Using Java 8 though - shouldn't matter anyways)

Create a configuration class annotated with @Configuration like so:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecretsConfig {

    public ApplicationSecretsConfig(){}

    @Value("${aws.secretsManager.secretName}")
    private String secretName;

    public String getSecretName(){
      return secretName;
    }
}
```

Then in your class, autowire the SecretsConfig dependency and get the value of secretName using its getter.

```
// class initialization done here

...
@Autowired
ApplicationSecretsConfig applicationSecretsConfig

public String getSecret() {
    
String secret = applicationSecretsConfig.getSecretName();
    
    // continue your logic
    ...
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to do a custom implementation for fetch secrets. Spring provides it, using [spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.4.1/reference/html/index.html#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-secrets-manager) dependency, just need to do an small config:

```
spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:my-secret
```

there is working sample on documentation:
https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/tree/main/spring-cloud-aws-samples/spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-sample

and here you could find a db working too:
https://github.com/nekperu15739/aws-secrets-manager

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your code in a next way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
class MyConfigClass(@Value("\${aws.secretsManager.secretName:}")val secretName:String?) {


fun getSecret() {


    val region = "us-west-2"
    val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetSecretConfig::class.java)

    // Create a Secrets Manager client
    val client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region).build()
    val getSecretValueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest().withSecretId(secretName)

    var getSecretValueResult: GetSecretValueResult? = try {
        client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest)
    } 
}
}
```

@Value annotation is not applicable to local variable.