# AWS Secrets Management does not work with Flyway/Hikari

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, flyway, hikaricp, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to connect my multi tenant application with to `AWS RDS` database through the secrets manager through dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.secretsmanager</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-secretsmanager-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and instrouction described here for postgres: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/secretsManagement

My `application.yml` looks like:

```
    spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc-secretsmanager:postgresql://database-addres/postgres
    username: /secrets-location
    driver-class-name: com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerPostgreSQLDriver
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    user: /secrets-location
```

And afterthat I get an error with:

```
Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [com/smartorder/smartorder/application/configuration/tenant/FlywayConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'flyway' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

 Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
```

with a Flyway config bean:

```
    @Configuration
public class FlywayConfig {

    @Bean
    public Flyway flyway(DataSource dataSource) {
        Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
                .locations("db.migration/default")
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .schemas(TenantIdentifierResolver.PUBLIC_TENANT)
                .load();
        flyway.migrate();
        return flyway;
    }
```

Anyone knows who to fix it?

Comment: That error is referring to the AWS region not being specified in the AWS credential chain. How are you providing AWS IAM credentials to this process?

Comment: Well, thats actually all what I did with aws...

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Are you saying you haven't configured the AWS credentials for this process yet at all? Where is this code running, locally? Or on an EC2 instance or something inside AWS?

Comment: Well, following that tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIbr6-AR6T8 there was no needed

Comment: How would this process gain access to your secrets stored in AWS without providing it credentials somehow? I'll ask again: Where is this code running, locally? Or on an EC2 instance or something inside AWS?

Comment: i try to run it locally

Comment: You need to setup AWS credentials locally using one of the methods described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: I provided just now Java system properties-aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey and still the same errors

Comment: You also need to provide the region, which is what the error message is telling you. See "Setting the region" here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html

Comment: I did it; like that: [default]
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = secret
region = eu-west-1 and still same errors

Answer (score 0):

the problem that i saw is that you are mixing configurations between flyway and spring. Even flyway its able to read secret manager, it doesn't add those properties to spring context. My recommendation here will be use awsspring that support secret manager integration and add those properties.

You could find more info on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66608801/this-annotation-is-not-applicable-to-target-local-variable/72716061#72716061)